# How to get locally my repository created on a shared host?

Tags: linux, git

On a shared host I have a website I would like to improve by adding it to git versioning system.

## On remote server

```
$cd public_html
$git init
$git add .
$git commit -m 'First Commit'
$cd .git
$ git config git-ftp.user myuser
$ git config git-ftp.password mypass
$ git config git-ftp.url ftp.mydomain.ro
```

## Locally linux mint/apache

Now how to I clone/get/use my repository from my local server?

I tried

```
$ git clone ftp://ftp.mydomain.ro/my-project.git
```

fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'ftp'

## UPDATED

I also tried to init an empty/bare repository:

```
git init --bare my-project.git
```

and locally

```
$git clone ssh://myuser@ftp.mydomain.ro/my-project.git
```

The aftermath is:

```
Cloning into ftp.mydomain.ro...
ssh: connect to host ftp.mydomain.ro port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: That clone command can't be the one you used, because it tries to clone a local directory named ./ftp.myomain.ro.  Can you please update the bug with actual instructions to reproduce your failure?

Comment: Well is not a bug, but I am looking for a git command to fetch locally the repo I created on the remote server. If clone is not good then what else?

Comment: @AndyRoss I did updated my spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
ssh://myuser@mydomain.ro:15554/home/mydomain/public_html/.git
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using specifying the ftp: scheme on the clone URL.

ftp://ftp.mydomain.ro

This tells git which protocol to use to access your remote.

Comment: I get the error fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'ftp.